# d3 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

Hi I am using a large json file in d3, about 75 KB. It seems to work for the 32 data objects but then I get the error in the console Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. It seems like my json is ok since I put it in http://jsonlint.com/ and it validated. I know similar questions have been asked here but I'm new to d3 so don't know how to modify the code. I think it may have something to do with how d3 is getting the data from my json file.
Here is d3 code in its entirety:

```
function truncate(str, maxLength, suffix) {
if(str.length > maxLength) {
    str = str.substring(0, maxLength + 1); 
    str = str.substring(0, Math.min(str.length, str.lastIndexOf(" ")));
    str = str + suffix;
}
return str;
}

var margin = {top: 20, right: 200, bottom: 0, left: 20},
    width = 300,
    height = 650;

var start_year = 2004,
    end_year = 2013;

var c = d3.scale.category20c();

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("top");

var formatYears = d3.format("0000");
xAxis.tickFormat(formatYears);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .style("margin-left", margin.left + "px")
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {
        if (error) throw error; 

x.domain([start_year, end_year]);
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([start_year, end_year])
    .range([0, width]);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 0 + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

console.log(data.length);   
var len = data.length;
for (var j = 0; j < len; j++) {
    // try{
    var g = svg.append("g").attr("class","journal");

    var circles = g.selectAll("circle")
        .data(data[j]['articles'])
        .enter()
        .append("circle");

    var text = g.selectAll("text")
        .data(data[j]['articles'])
        .enter()
        .append("text");

    var rScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data[j]['articles'], function(d) { return d[1]; })])
        .range([2, 9]);

    circles
        .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return xScale(d[0]); })
        .attr("cy", j*20+20)
        .attr("r", function(d) { return rScale(d[1]); })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return c(j); });

    text
        .attr("y", j*20+25)
        .attr("x",function(d, i) { return xScale(d[0])-5; })
        .attr("class","value")
        .text(function(d){ return d[1]; })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return c(j); })
        .style("display","none");

    g.append("text")
        .attr("y", j*20+25)
        .attr("x",width+20)
        .attr("class","label")
        .text(truncate(data[j]['name'],30,"..."))
        .style("fill", function(d) { return c(j); })
        .on("mouseover", mouseover)
        .on("mouseout", mouseout);
    // }
    // catch(err){
    //  console.log(err);
    //  continue;
    // }
};

function mouseover(p) {
    var g = d3.select(this).node().parentNode;
    d3.select(g).selectAll("circle").style("display","none");
    d3.select(g).selectAll("text.value").style("display","block");
}

function mouseout(p) {
    var g = d3.select(this).node().parentNode;
    d3.select(g).selectAll("circle").style("display","block");
    d3.select(g).selectAll("text.value").style("display","none");
}


});
```

Sample json:

```
[{"articles":[[2004,25],[2005,25],[2006,26],[2007,31],[2008,20],[2009,26],[2010,19],[2011,18],[2012,24],[2013,17]],"total": 231,"name": " Acta Inf. " }, 
{"articles":[[2008,1]],"total": 1,"name": " nf. " }, 
{"articles":[[2005,27],[2006,30],[2007,27],[2008,75],[2009,31],[2010,34],[2011,46],[2012,35],[2013,60]],"total": 365,"name": " Displays " }, 
{"articles":[[2010,20],[2011,16],[2012,16]],"total": 52,"name": " IJKDB " }, 
{"articles":[[2004,61],[2005,70],[2006,72],[2007,71],[2008,79],[2009,65],[2010,80],[2011,77],[2012,82],[2013,121]],"total": 778,"name": " Computers in Industry " }, 
{"articles":[[2010,1]],"total": 1,"name": " rs in Industry " }, 
{"articles":[[2005,1]],"total": 1,"name": " ry " }, ...
```

EDIT: no longer getting the error in console, there was something wrong with my JSON..however still not displaying all entries in the visualization, here is my entire JSON file https://api.myjson.com/bins/425wh

EDIT 2: it all displays now! all the data was there but wasn't showing up because the height of the d3 canvas was too small

Comment: In what line are you getting the error? Is it in `console.log(data.length);`?

Comment: line 117, its inside the for loop, and console.log(data.length) prints fine

Comment: Okay, so the problem is in `.text(truncate(data[j]['name'],30,"..."))`. 
Try printing `data[j]['name']`, should print undefined and that's where the problem lays.

Comment: It works fine as you've posted it: https://jsfiddle.net/h34smunq

Comment: it works for a few..but I have like 400 plus entries that I would like to display and only 30 or so are displaying

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce the problem with what you've posted.

Comment: https://api.myjson.com/bins/3t521 here is my entire json file

Comment: Looks like your JSON isn't correct -- when I log the elements inside the loop, I'm getting a list of things instead of a single one at some point.

Comment: hm it looks like you are right..I found the error and fixed it and no longer get the TypeError..however its still stops displaying the visualizations after like 30 entries..here is the new json file that is correct I believe https://api.myjson.com/bins/425wh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the last entry. The last entry is an array which is in correct it should have be an object, so your dataset has array within array in the last record. You will need to flatten your data set array.

Add this after fetching the data from AJAX.

```
data = [].concat.apply([], data);//this will flatten all your array within array into a single array of records,
```

### Edit

Second problem:

> I only see a few that actually show up? for example the Journal with name "Artificial Intelligence in Education" does not appear.

The problem is that the svg height is less and the data to be displayed is more so it cuts off after 30 records.

So have a dynamic height like this:

```
d3.select("body svg").attr("height",len*20.2);//20.2 is approx height of one element
```

Now height will depend on the data length that needs to displayed.

I have updated the fiddle accordingly

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NM2Ze5TMpPwKP6U9ULho?p=preview).

Comment: Ya I definitely had an error in the JSON file before, I just edited my post with a link to the  new JSON file in its entirety. But now the issue is its still not displaying all entries in d3

Comment: check my answer and fiddle i am using your same JSON..and it works the problem is that the array is not flattened

Comment: after flatten your array it will have 986 records earlier it was 486

Comment: hm but each entry should have its own distinct visualization..I only see a few that actually show up? for example the Journal with name "Artificial Intelligence in Education" does not appear

Comment: Updated my answer and fiddle to cater to the second problem.